# what event is called when all the controls on a screen is populated

Tags: c#, wpf

Can any one please tell what is the event which gets called when the controls on  a wpf window is shown and all data is populated?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `Loaded` event

```
<Window ...
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

> **FrameworkElement.Loaded Event**
>
> Occurs when the element is laid out, rendered, and ready for
>   interaction.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx

and go to "Window Lifetime"

**Eidt:**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx

This explains the difference between initialisation and loading event.